# Including <d3dkmthk.h> causes errors 'E0090 function returning function is not allowed'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, directx

In a x64 dll project on Visual Studio, adding this line :

`#include <d3dkmthk.h>`

gives me hundeds of errors like these :

```
Error (active)    E0090    function returning function is not allowed
Error    C2059    syntax error: '__cdecl'
Error    C2143    syntax error: missing ';' before '__cdecl'
Error    C4430    missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Comment: Your question is a C++ question, not C. Is this also a MCVE?

Comment: I guess you are right, I wrote the question before actually having the answer, which led me into adding information that ended up being unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`, deleting this line solved the issue.

Comment: ``#include <d3dkmthk.h>`` is a kernel-mode header in the Windows Driver Kit. You shouldn't be using it in user-mode programs.

Comment: I was writing a directx detour, importing it allowed me to use some structures in my wrapping functions.